# pandas handling of numpy timedelta64[ms]

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'0.11.0'
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.7.1'
>>> d={'a':np.array([68614867, 72200835], dtype=np.dtype('timedelta64[ms]'))}
>>> d['a'][0]
numpy.timedelta64(68614867,'ms')
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
>>> print df
            a
0 00:00:00.068615
1 00:00:00.072201
```

It looks like it is interpreting the values in the underlying `int64` as ns not ms. Is this a bug in pandas' handling of `timedelta64[ms]` types?

Answer (score 2):

timedelta handling is still a work-in-progress, see this issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3009

main issue is that timedeltas are broken in numpy 1.6.2.

passing of arbitrary timedeltas dtypes in creation is not supported yet, as
a workaround, you can do this, as the ONLY dtype supported at the moment is the
internal timedelta64[ns] (this is exactly how datetime64[ns]) works btw. Pandas
converts to an internal repr and then you do want you want.

(this solution is ONLY good for numpy >= 1.7).

```
In [22]: d['a'].astype('timedelta64[ns]')
Out[22]: array([68614867000000, 72200835000000], dtype='timedelta64[ns]')

In [23]: DataFrame(dict(a = d['a'].astype('timedelta64[ns]')))
Out[23]: 
                a
0 19:03:34.867000
1 20:03:20.835000

In [24]: DataFrame(dict(a = d['a'].astype('timedelta64[ns]'))).dtypes
Out[24]: 
a    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

what is the final goal you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm using pandas to process data as one of the stages in a computation. I would ideally like to be able to retrieve the data in the same form it was fed in i.e. both type and value. Also handling of datetime64 and timedelta64 is not consistent. In the former pandas appears to maintain the type info (i.e. remains timedelta64[ms] but pretty prints incorrectly) whereas for datetime64[D] or datetime64[M] pandas converts to datetime[ns].

Comment: I suggest you have a look at: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html, anhttp://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#time-deltas, the datetime64[ns] and timedelta64[ns] storage formats allow for much flexibility and pandas supports them internally. It is quite straightforward to convert to any other format.