# Wrong result from timedelta operation

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, timedelta

*dta_h* is is a DataFrame and *dta_h.Datetime* looks like this:

```
0    2013-03-01 00:00:00
1    2013-02-28 23:00:00
2    2013-02-28 22:00:00
3    2013-02-28 21:00:00
...
Name: Datetime, Length: 63001, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Until recently (I'll explain later what this means) I could do this to subtract one hours of each time period:

```
dta_h.Datetime-np.timedelta(hours=1)
```

But now, if I do the above, I am getting this:

```
0    2013-03-01 00:11:34.967296
1    2013-02-28 23:11:34.967296
2    2013-02-28 22:11:34.967296
3    2013-02-28 21:11:34.967296
...
```

Which clearly is not what I want. However, this:

```
[i-timedelta(hours=1) for i in dta_h.Datetime ]
```

still yields the desirted result:

```
0    2013-02-28 23:00:00
1    2013-02-28 22:00:00
2    2013-02-28 21:00:00
3    2013-02-28 20:00:00
....
Length: 63001, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I am 99% sure that this problem started when I upgraded to Pandas 0.11. I have been looking around in the documentation for any difference in the version that might explain it without success. I also found this posting:

[pandas handling of numpy timedelta64[ms]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288320/pandas-handling-of-numpy-timedelta64ms/16290044#16290044)

which refers to this Pandas issue

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3009

Based on what I read there, I tried:

```
dta_h.Datetime-np.timedelta64(hours=1)
```

But this actually does nothing:

```
0    2013-03-01 00:00:00
1    2013-02-28 23:00:00
2    2013-02-28 22:00:00
3    2013-02-28 21:00:00
...
```

Any idea why 1) the df-np.timedelta stopped working, and 2) why the comprehension list version still works? Thanks for you help.

FYI, I am using Numpy 1.6.2 and, a I said earlier, recently upgraded from Pandas 0.9 to 0.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy is quite buggy in 1.6.2/1 for timedeltas. It works for intervals < 30minutes (I have no idea why). Best bet is to upgrade to numpy 1.7.0/1 much more stable, and use datetime.timedelta

```
In [33]: df = DataFrame(dict(date = [Timestamp('20130301'),Timestamp('20130228 23:00:00'),Timestamp('20130228 22:00:00'),Timestamp('20130228 21:00:00')]))

In [34]: df
Out[34]: 
                 date
0 2013-03-01 00:00:00
1 2013-02-28 23:00:00
2 2013-02-28 22:00:00
3 2013-02-28 21:00:00

In [37]: df['date'] + timedelta(hours=1)
Out[37]: 
0   2013-03-01 01:00:00
1   2013-03-01 00:00:00
2   2013-02-28 23:00:00
3   2013-02-28 22:00:00
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [38]: np.__version__
Out[38]: '1.7.1'
```

Comment: Upgraded to 1.7.1 and...problem solved! Many thanks for the help. I'm sticking to Pandas 0.11 and Numpy 1.7.1 for now as a stable combination.

Comment: yep....we are going to fix the 1.6.2 stuff, but numpy very buggy there: see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/4138

Answer (score 1):

You can use the time in nanoseconds:

```
In [11]: df - pd.np.timedelta64(60*60*10**9)  # one hour in nanoseconds
Out[11]:
                     date
index
0     2013-02-28 23:00:00
1     2013-02-28 22:00:00
2     2013-02-28 21:00:00
3     2013-02-28 20:00:00
```

Keyword arguments appear to be ignored by timedelta64:

```
In [12]: df - pd.np.timedelta64(foo=60*60*10**9)
Out[12]:
                     date
index
0     2013-03-01 00:00:00
1     2013-02-28 23:00:00
2     2013-02-28 22:00:00
3     2013-02-28 21:00:00
```

It feels like you ought to be able to use pandas offsets:

```
df.date - pd.offsets.Hour(1)
ValueError: cannot operate on a series with out a rhs of a series/ndarray of type datetime64[ns] or a timedelta
```

At the moment you can do this with an apply or the delta attribute:

```
In [21]: df.date.apply(lambda t: t - pd.offsets.Hour(1))
Out[21]:
index
0       2013-02-28 23:00:00
1       2013-02-28 22:00:00
2       2013-02-28 21:00:00
3       2013-02-28 20:00:00
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [22]: df.date - pd.offsets.Hour(1).delta
Out[22]:
index
0       2013-02-28 23:00:00
1       2013-02-28 22:00:00
2       2013-02-28 21:00:00
3       2013-02-28 20:00:00
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: the last operation is still buggy in 1.6.2 (not really sure why, but for smaller values is works)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. This solution works. But is just a workaround for a bug. So I rather upgrade to 1.7.0/.1 as suggested by Jeff.

Comment: NumPy 1.7.1 is __still broken__: everything passed to `np.timedelta64` is interpreted as nanosecond, regardless of arguments.

Comment: @dmvianna My understanding is that timedelta64 is in nanoseconds, I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @dmvianna perhaps it's worth posting [a pandas github issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues) about this :s